# How do I create a loop from a list resuting from a previous command?

Tags: solaris, ksh

I would like to create a script that would list all owners of all the sub directories then check each ID if I have access to sesu to the IDs.

```
**$**ls -lrth /apps/wldomains | grep '^d' | awk '{ print $3 }'
userid1
userid2
userid3
userid4
.
.
.

**$**sesu - userid1
Please enter your password:
**userid1@SERVER:$**sesu - userid2
Please enter your password:
**userid2@SERVER:$**sesu - userid3
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2):

use printf feature of awk, then pipe to ksh.

```
ls -lrth /apps/wldomains | awk '$1 ~/^d/ { printf "sesu %s\n", $3 }'
```

should generate

```
sesu userid1
sesu userid2
sesu userid3
sesu userid4
```

simply add `| ksh` when OK

```
ls -lrth /apps/wldomains | awk '$1 ~/^d/ { printf "sesu %s\n", $3 }'| ksh
```

- I also compacted `grep | awk` in `awk`

Answer (score 1):

[Without parsing `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls):

```
find /apps/wldomains -type d -exec stat -c %U {} \; | sort -u | xargs -n 1 sesu -
```

- `find /apps/wldomains -type d` will find all directories under `/apps/wldomains` (including `/apps/wldomains` itself).
- `stat -c %U` will output the user name of the owner of the found directory.
- `sort -u` will take these user names and sort them into a list of distinct user names.
- `xargs -n 1 sesu -` will take this list and execute `sesu -` for each of them.

On Solaris, install the GNU coreutils package and use `gstat` in place of `stat`.